# How to get User roles on discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

New discord.py-rewrite user here.

I'm coding a bot that has a discord interface: It is connected to more than one server (guild) and I currently need an auth system to limit its use.
I thought I could get all users roles and parse them later when needed. So I did:

```
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        ... 
        for guild in client.guilds:
            for member in guild.members:
                for role in member.roles:
                    if role.name == "Test":
                        print("USER_ID: %d - ROLE: %s" % (member.id, role.name))
```

but I don't like it. I have to store these and its not efficient. Also I have to refresh with a background co-routine to check if new members join/changed roles.
So my question: is there a simply way to check on the fly user roles on mutual guilds when receiving a message?
Scrolling the official API the only way to get user's mutual guilds is profile() but as a bot I get a Forbidden Error, like API says.

```
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        ...
        profile = await message.author.profile()
```

```
discord.errors.Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Bots cannot use this endpoint
```

(update) ADDENDUM:

I need to check user's roles even in private messages so the need to get mutual_guilds

Comment: You would have to create your own function to find mutual guilds for a given user. That function would need to loop through all guilds the bot is connected to and check if the user exists within that guild. That said, it seems odd that you are looking across all guilds for a users permissions in order to perform an action in private messages. What exactly is this authorization meant to limit? Would it be simpler to have the user register with the bot itself for authorization instead of a guild role? What happens if the user has the role in one guild but not in another?

Comment: how "register with tbe bot itself for an authorization" would be simpler then some nested for cycles?

Comment: Would require some sort of external storage (database or file). User performs registration command, gets logged into storage, bot references storage for performing actions that require "authorization"

Comment: yeah, I thought about that but I would keep the user experience simpler (aka no  user action required).

Comment: Do the commands performed via direct messages with the bot have any impact on the guilds the user is in? I asked this previously, but, what happens if I have the role in one guild but I don't in another?

Comment: Here Discord is used only for input/output. The guild has no impact on the actions. If user has the right role in just one server it should be good enough to start the interaction..

Comment: Noted. That scenario to me strengthens the argument to simply register with the bot but it's up to you if you don't want the individual user to go through that. That said though, someone would still be required to give the user this specific role. So either way, a user does need to do something for the bot to function... be it someone give me a role, or I register with the bot.

Comment: I prefer guild admins do the dirty work :) - ty anu6is for your advices!

Comment: lol, no problem.

Comment: Do you mean Pycord?

Answer (score 0):

I have looked trough the Documentation, and I don't think there is simpler way to do this.

```py
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(self, ctx):
    for role in ctx.guild.roles:
        if role.name == 'Your role name':
            #Code
```

Simply when certain command is called, you check for each role on the guild the message was sent in, and if the role name matches the role name you pick, it will execute certain code.

Comment: Problem is I need to check roles (and do permissions check) even via private message, so the need to mutual_guilds